# remove context menu items for standard account in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

Is there a way i can remove context menu items for only a standard account and not the administrator account in windows 7, especially from the desktop context menu?

Comment: If the entries are under HKCU they should only affect the currently logged in account.

Comment: @Karan thanx for suggestion. But I cannot find any context-menu handlers for HKCU/HKU. Changing the ones in the Root should affect all users.